# Rewrite rule to redirect two friendly urls to same file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, friendly-url

I'm trying to redirect two different url to the same file.

The url are: `http://localhost/CLIENTI/HOTEL/cp/amministratori` and `http://localhost/CLIENTI/HOTEL/cp/amministratori/test`

Actually i currently see the first url, but when I open the second one i see a lot of error of files inclusion on client side (es js and css files on header/footer).

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^dashboard$ dashboard.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^amministratori$ dashboard.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^amministratori/test$ dashboard.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

that was all my htaccess code. The errors are 404 of bootstrap.js and main.js which contains custom code for the frontend. I've understood the problem but I've haven't undersood if there is a solution alternative to the leading slash, because my header and footer are included in php, so in `/cp/amministratori` they work as now, but obviously if I change with a leading slash they will not work anymore

Comment: _“i see a lot of error of files inclusion”_ - properly explain what that actually means. (I have a suspicion that you are not talking about actual includes on the PHP side here, but about embedded resources on the client side …?)

Comment: yes I mean those kind of error

Comment: That’s because you are changing the folder depth of the path on the client side. `amministratori/test` is one level of folders more, than just `amministratori` (which is what you are actually redirecting in the first case, according to your code, and not `amministratori/` as you said) - so relative URLs won’t work, you need to use URLs starting with a leading slash, referring to the web root.

Comment: @johnnydeppa, Please do let us know if you have any more htaccess Rules also in your htaccess file? Apart from shown ones? Also please do mention what kind of errors you are seeing in accessing those links? Thank you.

Comment: that was all my htaccess code. The errors are 404 of bootstrap.js and main.js which contains custom code for the frontend. I've undersood the problem but i've haven't undersoot if there is a solution alternative to the leading slash, because my header and footer are included in php, so in /cp/amministratori they work as now, but obsiously if i change with a leading slash they will not work anymore

Comment: You are not supposed to change the path of the files you include on the server side (nothing has changed there, the script you are executing is still `dashboard.php`, same location as before), but the relative URLs you are using to embed these external resources on the client side.

Comment: yes i meant those url path, in amministratori url i use link as src="js/main.js" while in amministratori/test i have to use src="../js/main.js", but i can't as i have the same footer for both pages

Comment: And that’s why I said, use `/js/main.js` instead. (The `base` element as mentioned in Ravinder’s answer, achieves the same thing in a slightly different way.)

Comment: i've tried with /js/main.js but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown attempts, please try following htaccess Rules. Make sure to place your htaccess file along with CLIENTI folder(not inside it).

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /CLIENTI/HOTEL/cp/amministratori/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ dashboard.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?$ dashboard.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/?$ dashboard.php [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

JS/CS rewrite/redirect:
You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.